# What does the number after @ in thread view in Intellij IDEA mean?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

What does `954` mean? I have checked both thread's id and hashcode(), but they don't equal 954.

[image]

Also, when using evaluate, there is also a number after `@`, I think they have the same meaning but still couldn't find out what's the meaning.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I just always took for granted that it is some id that uniquely identifies the object.

Based on that assumption it could for example be the uniqueId() returned by the Java Debugger Interface for an ObjectReference:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/

But that is really just an assumption.